# how to change the color of the listView text in android

Tags: android

i've chose de default navigation drawer activity from my IDE, I’ve set the list view items, but i want to change to default color (white) to a custom color black per example. There Is the code That i've tried

```
//Set Black Color for the text

    textView=(TextView) getText(android.R.id.text1);
    textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_grey));
    textView.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
    textView.setTextSize((float) 20);

    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1,
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.title_section1),
                    getString(R.string.title_section2),
                    getString(R.string.title_section3),
                    getString(R.string.title_section4),
                    getString(R.string.title_section5),
                    getString(R.string.title_section6),
            }));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
```

Comment: use custom xml instead of android default xml for `ListView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possibilities. First one is to use Android's built in layouts (like you did), and override getView() in the adapter to change the text color, like so:

```
mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
            new String[] { 
                getString(R.string.title_section1),
                getString(R.string.title_section2),
                getString(R.string.title_section3),
                getString(R.string.title_section4),
                getString(R.string.title_section5), 
                getString(R.string.title_section6)}) {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.whatever));
            return textView;
        }
    });
```

The second option is to create your own layout xml file, and simply set the text color attribute in that layout's text view.

Comment: the location of the getView function is false i guess !

Comment: What do you mean by false? This is working code, it's an anonymous class implementation.

Comment: how can i added this function with regard to my code ?

Comment: Replace your call to `setAdapter()` with the one I posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change color programmatically, try to change text color from listview's xml.

Comment: Could you please show simple_list_item_1.xml file's code?